# is there any way to install AIX on a normal desktop for practice purpose?

Tags: unix, aix

is is possible with any emulator like QEMU or PearPC ?

or if not possible where can we get AIX box access ?

Answer (score 2):

The short, and long, answer is no. IBM does not, and by any account has not, any intention of opening their OS to architectures other than their own.

If your budget is intended to include support, I'd give IBM a call, otherwise have a look on ebay!

Without hands-on it's not easy, I know, but it's not open source. The good news is if you do find some hardware, the AIX 7 beta is free to download.